# PHP instant messaging methods

Tags: php, sockets, chat, comet, polling

I want to make an IM so that user's can send instant messages to each others on the same page like a chat. Users can choose that who can see their messages. Its for task management . What is the best method that I should use for. I'm using php. Is php sockets  usefull for this? or Polling, Comet, php output buffer or javascript timer(timer is easy but not fast).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most frequently used method is called [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Here is a PHP implementation: [How to implement COMET with PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

In the HTML5 specification there are something called websockets that many browsers already have implemented. Here is a PHP project supporting websockets: [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/). There are some javascript libraries which can use a flash component if the browser do not support websockets (and therefore be backwards compatible)

imho webSockets is the way to go, although PHP might not be the most suitable backend to handle them.

Comment: What would be a better language then I wonder?

Comment: Any language that works well outside a webserver (it's better to write/use a separate websocket server than running an implementation in a webserver)

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to use `Sockets` then use them; otherwise using AJAX in a timer should suffice so long as it doesn't need to be real-time (5-10 second delays between fetching messages should be OK).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using Socket.IO for this.

Comment: thanks to everyone for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options from PHP:

1. As pointed out by @jgauffin you could look doing this on your existing PHP server using a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) using the [Comet and PHP option](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) or WebSocket Solution using something like [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/).
2. You could create another component dedicated to handling your real-time messaging such as a dedicated Comet or WebSockets process running on you existing hosting or a wholly dedicated server. If you take this approach you could look at using something like [socket.io](http://socket.io) running in node.js or a full third party Comet or WebSockets server.
3. Finally, you could have a look at a hosted service which would allow you to keep your existing development and production environment and you could then layer on the real-time chat. One such service called [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (which I work on) handles all the real-time messaging infrastructure in addition to providing added functionality specifically developed for making chat applications easy to build. It also means that you don't need to upgrade your hosting if you are using something like shared hosting where things are tightly locked down and you can't easily install your own components.